# Redirect a Fb app request notification to the app requests page

Tags: facebook, notifications, request

I'm developing a Fb app, and occasionally the app sends user-generated requests to other users.  These requests show up as notifications at the top of the Fb homepage.  When a user clicks on these, he or she is redirected to the app canvas page on Fb, whereas I would like the user to see the actual text/description of the request (on the App requests page).

How can I redirect a user from a notification to the App requests page, or otherwise show the user the text of the request?  I know Farmville does it this way: request notifications redirect to the "Game requests" page.  How is this done?

Thanks for your help,

TS

Answer (score 0):

You can display a desired page based on **requests_ids** argument passed to application canvas URL.

From **User Response** paragraph of [Request Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) documentation:

> If a user clicks 'Accept' on a request, they will be sent to the
>   canvas URL of the application that sent the request. This URL will
>   contain an additional parameter, request_ids, which is a comma
>   delimited list of Request IDs that a user is trying to act upon:
>
> `http://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have a followup question: If the app is bookmarked, when you click it there the canvas request does not contain a list of "request_ids". Therefore, there's no specific apprequest to display on the canvas page. I could either a) figure out the most recent apprequest worth displaying or b) display a list of X most recent (relevant) apprequests. What do you think is the best practice of displaying apprequests on the canvas page for server requests originated from the bookmark link?

Comment: It's really depend on your application needs, consider asking this as separate question to get more attention to subject